# How to replace all from a certain letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to replace from a letter to the end or to the start.

Lets say i have a string: `i love apples` i want to be able to search for `a` which is the beginning of `apples` and from there replace everything before it! So i am left with apples. Same goes for, search for `a` and replace everything from a upwards so i am left with `i love`

My JS only finds word and delete, how do i make it do the above? Thanks!

JS:

```
var queuestring2 = $(this).html();
queuestring2 = queuestring2.replace("path", "");
$(this).html(queuestring2);
```

Comment: You can do the first part like `var str = "i love apples".replace(/.*(?=a)/,"");
` which will result `apples`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var myString = "I love apples";
var letter = "a";
var index = myString.indexOf(letter);

//Remove everything before 'a'
var endString = myString.slice(index);

//Remove everything after 'a'
var startString = myString.slice(0, index);

console.log("Remove before -"+letter+"- : " + endString);
console.log("Remove after -"+letter+"- : " + startString);
```